# Set bullet instead of dot using \dot

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I would like to place a bullet in the same way that `$\dot{x}$` places a dot above x. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 15):

Another clear case for the `accents` package: [image: output].

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
$\accentset{\bullet}{x}$
\end{document}
```

Note that, in contrast to `\overset`,  the slant of the letters is taken care of automatically:

[image: comparison with \overset]

Answer (score 14):

Here you go:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$A \overset{\bullet}{B} C$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be worth editing your question to clarify, then, as that's the first thing everyone will see when they click this thread.

Answer (score 3):

I used the `\;` to add some horizontal space before the bullet, to account for the fact that the under-letter will be set in italic which is generally slanted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\overset{\;\bullet} B
\]
\end{document}
```